# What is the role of the output.config file generated for a webservice?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I generated a class file for a webservice in visual basic I am trying to use to connect to a third party application for authentication.

When I ran the command line commands to generate the class files for the webservice I also found an output.config file generated with it.

What is the role of this file, and where should I put it to ensure the application can communicate successfully with the webservice?

By "where should I put it" I mean, should it go in the same folder as the webservice class file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I generated a class file for a webservice in visual basic [...]

I assume you used [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)? Svcutil creates not only the client code but also configuration to go with it. The configuration is in the `output.config` file. Inside it you will find such things like [client endpoint, binding configuration or endpoint behaviours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733107.aspx).

You will need to [copy the configurations you find inside `output.config`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734663.aspx) and place it inside your `App.config` file or `Web.config` file (depending of the type of application you have).

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem. I copied it into my web.config file and now it runs error-free.