# How to understand what XML to send to an ASMX web service?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, service, asmx

I am trying to consume some .asmx service in a console application (I will later use the code to make a dll and use it somewhere else).

But I don't know what the schema of the web service is. I just know the URL of the service which on navigating using the browser gives a page which enlists the functions of the web service. On clicking on a function I get a page with this written under the heading

> SOAP 1.1:
>
> The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

And after this there is some XML with tags like `<soap:Envelope>`, `<soap:body>` etc. But  I can't use those XMLs...

How do I understand the XML required for a call having only this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for the "Service Description" link in that page.

ASP.NET generates those pages to allow you to test the service. In the pages there is a link to the [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) of the web service (normally the endpoint address with `?wsdl` appended to it).

The WSDL is all you need to generate a client to interact with the web service. Feed that to a tool like [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) and you get back client code and [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767174/what-is-the-role-of-the-output-config-file-generated-for-a-webservice/).